# Securely parse XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, string, security

I have a C# application that receives a byte array from an external service that represents a UTF-8 encoded XML message. This XML data contains sensitive data that I would prefer not to have stored in a string object since strings are immutable and I cannot wipe the values when I am done with them. I am currently using System.XML.XmlReader to parse the values out as strings (see code below). How can I go about doing this without having my code (or the code I am calling) store the sensitive data as a string?

```
        byte[] messsage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request);
        // Send message to the server. 
        sslStream.Write(messsage);
        sslStream.Flush();

        // read the response
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        StringBuilder messageData = new StringBuilder();
        int bytes = -1;
        do
        {
            bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            // Use Decoder class to convert from bytes to UTF8
            // in case a character spans two buffers.
            Decoder decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
            char[] chars = new char[decoder.GetCharCount(buffer, 0, bytes)];
            decoder.GetChars(buffer, 0, bytes, chars, 0);
            messageData.Append(chars);
            // Check for ending tag.
            if (messageData.ToString().IndexOf(expectedEndTag) != -1)
            {
                break;
            }
        } while (bytes > 0);

        string response = messageData.ToString();

        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(response)))
        {
            reader.ReadToFollowing("Success");
            string successVal = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
            success = bool.Parse(successVal);
        }
```

Comment: Encrypt the value.  It should be encrypted anyway when it's being transmitted from the external service because some bad actor could intercept the data.

Comment: "This XML data contains sensitive data that I would prefer not to have stored in a string object since strings are immutable and I cannot wipe the values when I am done with them".  See SecureString.  It's meant to be confidential and not kept in memory.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you're just worried about the strings sitting around in memory you could look into using SecureString, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @rory.ap the data is encrypted in transit, but this is the point where I need to get the data out unencrypted but I wanted it stored in a byte[] as opposed to a string. The sensitive data in the XML file is hex encoded.

Comment: @Gaber-ber I have looked into SecureString but I don't see how I can use it in this context to still parse the XML. Do you have an example of parsing the XML using SecureString?

Comment: Do you have a particular threat profile where you need to defend against authorised but less-trusted parties with access to the machine? If not, for the general case, trying to worry about keeping secrets out of memory is a massive waste of time. Too many people see SecureString and think it offers general security, when actually it's targeted at a particular (unusual and questionable) use case.

Comment: @bobince I agree, if the host machine is compromised then there is little to nothing I can do to really protect the data on the system. That being said, certain standards (e.g., PCI) care about this kind of stuff and we are trying to deal with an auditor that wants to know how we can guarantee that this sensitive information isn't sitting around in memory after we make use of it and since the XML parsing is currently using a string I don't have a good answer for him.

Comment: At the time of writing, PCI-DSS has no requirement for in-memory secret protection. And as you say, parsing it from serialised forms without decrypting it is impossible anyway. What you may want to do is spend some time ensuring that in-memory storage really *is* only volatile and doesn't accidentally write potentially-secret data to permanent storage locations where it isn't expected. This can mean ensuring any crash dumps are disabled or suitably protected, and you don't have system or VM virtual memory paging out your volatile storage to disc.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer, and given the fact that a string is immutable, you should write your own XML parser that uses char[]. After you're done with the parsing, wipe the char array content. To use the sensitive data in the program, use the [SecureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx) as the @Ga ber-ber and @Mumbo suggested in the comments.

It's hard and work duplication, but this way you'll be sure that the memory is wiped right after parsing.